# Java Spring deserializing ISO Zulu time error

Tags: java, date, datetime, parsing, postman

I am trying to parse dates with the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`. I have a controller with a POST endpoint which takes an object. In that object is a date field of object type "Instant". it has the following annotations:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
@JsonSerialize(using = InstantSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultInstantDeserializer.class)
private Instant endTime;
```

I had to create the DefaultInstantDeserializer because using the provided one gave me an error because InstantDeserializer (from the jackson-datatype library) has no no-args constructor.

This is that class

```
public class DefaultInstantDeserializer extends InstantDeserializer<Instant> {
    public DefaultInstantDeserializer() {
        super(Instant.class, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT,
                Instant::from,
                a -> Instant.ofEpochMilli(a.value),
                a -> Instant.ofEpochSecond(a.integer, a.fraction),
                null,
                true // yes, replace zero offset with Z
        );
    }
}
```

using Postman, I sent the object, with that field being `2022-02-08T15:22:24+00:00`

I get this error from in the logs from Spring:

```
Failed to deserialize java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2022-02-08T15:14:28+00:00' could not be parsed at index 19\n
```

It looks like it cannot parse the time starting at `+00:00`. I thought the Z indicated Zulu time/ GMT/ UTC time, which is a 0 offset. Is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` not a valid date format? My requirements say I must use that pattern. In Postman the pattern I am using to send the data is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`. There is some disconnect between the 0 offset and the Z value, I thought the deserializer would take care of that, but I think not. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `+00:00` is a time offset, it is not Zulu. It may represent the same Zulu time, but technically it is a time offset so with a specific syntax. Your `Z` will not parse `[+|-]hh:mm[:ss[.dddd]]` format.

Comment: You're repeating defaults and explicitly saying a literal `Z`. Simply remove all the annotations from your property and it should Just Work.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- remove all annotations or just the JsonFormat pattern?

Comment: All of it. If you have the `JavaTimeModule` registered, `Instant` is handled for you.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- That seemed to work, but now I have nanoseconds where I do not need to. `2022-02-08T16:54:09.670717700Z`. Can I fix this without using the json format annotation?

Comment: Those nanoseconds are actually there in the data. The usual approach would be to truncate the real value (so that comparisons will work correctly!), but you can use `@JsonFormat` to squash it.